# Using landslide in a sentence and paraphrazing it

Tags: meaning, word-choice

[image: demagouge]

As I see in the dictionary landslide can be :
a.  The downward sliding of  mass of earth 
b.  A percentage of votes greatly exceeding the required margin of victory.
Did they mean here to the first meaning? Metaphorically, the triumph of his opponent is deteriorating. Hence the demagogue feel euphoria. Did I understand it well?
By the way, why did they write  triumphs and not triumph?

Comment: [A landslide victory is an electoral victory in a political system, when one candidate or party receives an overwhelming majority of the votes or seats in the elected body, thus all but utterly eliminating the opponents.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landslide_victory) This is General Reference.

Comment: ...but I doubt the sample text was from a native speaker anyway, since *to give enthusiastic ovation* (with no article) is very unusual phrasing (particularly with a singular subject). UPDATE - it's [a bad translation](https://quizlet.com/47826788/gre-24-flash-cards/)

Comment: *Triumphs* is a verb: the opponent here wins by an overwhelming majority.

Answer (score 3):

Did they mean here to the first meaning?
Answer: no. It still means the second meaning of which you indicated: A percentage of votes greatly exceeding the required margin of victory.

Let's see the sentence:
The result is there's no sentence indicating that when used metaphorically in a campaign (especially an election) it would mean the other meaning. (And the subject is a demagogue would mean a **political** leader who seeks support by appealing to popular passions and prejudices).

You can see the **but** here is very important. It means that this 'demagogue' is a *special case*. We can conclude that "As a politician who gives enthusiastic ovation **"when his opponent triumphs"** in a landslide" s/he is a quirky one. And the ***first sentence emphasizes*** this more: A **demagogue** should never exude **euphoria** near the surface in a campaign. It's established in the first sentence that you, as a politician, shouldn't **exude** any **"euphoria"** or a **feeling of great or exaggerated elation**.

A demagogue should never exude **euphoria** near the surface in a campaign, ***but*** this politician gives enthusiastic ovation when his opponent triumphs in a landslice.

As for your first question about landslide,

**From Webster's**:

1 :  the usually rapid downward movement of a mass of rock, earth, or artificial fill on a slope; also :  the mass that moves down

2 a :  a great majority of votes for one side b :  **an overwhelming victory**

**From Oxford's Dictionary:**

1.A collapse of a mass of earth or rock from a mountain or cliff:

2.An **overwhelming majority of votes** for one party or candidate in an election: they won by a landslide

Example: She was expected to win by a **landslide**. 
Common Phrase: a **landslide victory**.

Usually being used in:
- Voting in elections
- Running for election 
- Conduct/hold an election/a referendum (especially North American English)
- Run for office/election/governor/mayor/president/the White House (especially British English)

Source: **http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/landslide**

**From Vocabulary.com :**

When dirt and rock from a mountainside coming sliding down, call it a **landslide.**

> Another kind of **landslide** takes place when **one candidate** *soundly defeats* **another in an election**. With either type of landslide, it's probably safest to stay out of the way! The political meaning of landslide is *commonly used*, but it's **not the word's original definition**.

In a political news:
"Trump is still dominating in the national polls and in most of the early primary states, save for Iowa. And that’s good news for Democrats: Both Clinton and Sanders lead Trump in head-to-head surveys, and would likely win in a **landslide**."

Source:
http://www.salon.com/2015/12/23/forget_donald_trump_democrats_marco_rubio_is_the_nightmare_that_could_strike_hillary_clinton/

So, we can conclude from these examples that this 'landslide' means your second meaning, i.e.: A percentage of votes greatly exceeding the required margin of victory.

When I researched your question:
**

> https://www.google.com/search?q=winning+in+a+landslide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

It is consistent throughout the searches that it means the second meaning.

**

Researching further for added references,

**Landslide election:**

**How Much a Landslide Election Is**

> One generally agreed upon measure of a landslide election is when the
>   winning candidate beats his opponent or opponents by at least 15
>   percentage points in a popular vote count.

Source: http://uspolitics.about.com/od/Electoral-College/a/How-Much-Is-A-Landslide.htm

===========

Regarding the ""triumphs" and not "triumph"", it is because of his opponent is "a singular" and ***triumphs*** here ***functions as a verb*** which means to express great joy because of winning something and is deemed as a verb.
It is also to indicate that:

... but **this politician** **gives** enthusiastic ovation when his opponent **triumphs** in a landslide.

It's called tenses consistency.
[image]
Source: http://www.towson.edu/ows/tenseconsistency.htm